# "Error: Received packet in the wrong sequence." when connect to serverless aurora

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-aurora, aws-sdk-js

I'm implementing a web application and it calls lambda function to get data from database.
I chose Serverless Aurora and wrote a code, but I get the exception `"Error: Received packet in the wrong sequence."` in query method.

I googled this issue but almost of all is too old.
An article said it is the problem of `browisify` but I don't use it.
I'm using serverless framework with typescript.

```js
const mysql = require('serverless-mysql')({
  config: {
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    database: process.env.DB_NAME,
    user: process.env.DB_USER,
    password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD
  }
});

export async function query(sql: string, param?: Array<string>): Promise<any> {
  const results = await mysql.query(sql).catch(e => {
    console.log(e); // Error: Received packet in the wrong sequence
    throw new Error(e);
  });

  await mysql.end();
  return results;
}
```

following also not working

```
export async function query(sql: string, param?: Array<string>): Promise<any> {
  const connQueryPromisified = util
    .promisify(connection.query)
    .bind(connection);
  const result = await connQueryPromisified(sql, param)
    .then(row => {
      console.log(row);
      return row;
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err); // getting Error: Received packet in the wrong sequence
      throw err;
    });
  return result;
}
```

I also tried to use RDS DATA Service but in my region it is not available.

```
export async function query(sql: string, param?: Array<string>): Promise<any> {
 const params: aws.RDSDataService.Types.ExecuteSqlRequest = {
    awsSecretStoreArn: '***',
    dbClusterOrInstanceArn: '***',
    database: '***',
    schema: '***',
    sqlStatements: sql
  };
  console.log(params);
  try {
    const rdsService = new aws.RDSDataService({
      apiVersion: '2018-08-01',
      region: 'ap-northeast-1'
    });
    return rdsService
      .executeSql(params)
      .promise()
      .then(d => {
        return d;
      })
      .catch(e => {
        throw new Error(e);
      });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err); // nothing to say
    throw new Error(err);
  }
}
```

And here is my configurations:
`webpack.config.js`

```
const path = require('path');
const slsw = require('serverless-webpack');

module.exports = {
  mode: slsw.lib.webpack.isLocal ? 'development' : 'production',
  entry: slsw.lib.entries,
  devtool: 'source-map',
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.json', '.ts', '.tsx'],
  },
  output: {
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs',
    path: path.join(__dirname, '.webpack'),
    filename: '[name].js',
  },
  target: 'node',
  module: {
    rules: [
      // all files with a `.ts` or `.tsx` extension will be handled by `ts-loader`
      { test: /\.tsx?$/, loader: 'ts-loader' },
    ],
  },
};
```

`tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": [
      "es2017"
    ],
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "outDir": "lib"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

I want to query only getting records from Serverless Aurora.
Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The reason this is happening is because Webpack (in production mode) is putting your code through a minimiser, and the `mysql` module that `serverless-mysql` is using is not compatible with minimising.

You can see the issue here: https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql/issues/1655. It's quite a common problem with Node modules which rely on function names to do code building, as uglyifiers/minifiers attempt to obfuscate/save space by changing the names of functions to single letters.

The simplest fix would be to switch off minimising in your webpack config by adding:

```
  optimization: {
    minimize: false
  }
```

There is some discussion in the linked issue on configuring various other minimising plugins (like terser) to *not* mangle names, which would allow you to get some of the benefit of minimising if you need it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [mysql2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2) which supports promises
https://stackoverflow.com/a/62255084/1031304